# Can an appositive noun not follow the noun in apposition to it?

Tags: appositives

> In ancient times, a great Chinese leader was born: Confucius.

**Confucius** is the appositive noun here, and **a great Chinese leader** is a noun in apposition to it.
Can "Confucius" and "a great Chinese leader" be separated like this?

Comment: Yes, but a comma rather than colons would serve the sentence better.

Comment: @RonaldSole I disagree. The colon is used correctly here and a comma would be wrong.

Comment: @TypeIA I shall reflect on the matter further!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, appositions typically only occur after the nouns they refer to:

> In ancient times, **Confucius, a great Chinese leader**, was born.

In your sentence, which is a paraphrased version of the one above, the direct noun-apposition relationship is lost, even though the semantic relationship remains the same (that's why we say it's a paraphrased version):

> In ancient times, **a great Chinese leader** was born: **Confucius**.

In the sentence above, some suspense is added by using a colon, causing the effect of an announcement. Syntactically, I think "Confucius" is the subject complement in a sentence where subject and verb have been elided:

> In ancient times, a great Chinese leader was born: **(he was)** Confucius.

Some grammarians consider this structure to be a concluding appositive. See, for example, [this page](https://natureofwriting.com/courses/punctuation/lessons/colons/topic/the-rules-for-colons/):

> An appositive is a noun or noun phrase that renames an earlier noun phrase. You can use a colon at the end of a sentence to introduce a **concluding appositive**:
>
> *Why is it that artists like Jake Bugg or “The Tallest Man on Earth” imitate Bob Dylan’s worst feature: nasal singing?*
>
> *You know there’s one thing I could really use this winter: a remote car-starter.*
>
> In the first example, “nasal singing” specifies what the “worst feature” is; in the second example, “a remote car-starter” clarifies what is meant by the “one thing.”